# Vuejs 404 resources not found

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I keep having this strange problem, if i add some extra

`{path: '/detailed-support', component: Detailed, name: 'detailed', children:[
        {path: 'start', component: Start, name: 'starting'}
    ]},`

When i try to access it manually just putting in the browser `http://localhost:8080/detailed-support/start` it loads the content, but it doesnt want to load images, or any resources that located in my folders. It gives an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

What could it be? in my dev inspector it points to this -> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">` as if there is something wrong with the path. But then why its working when im in the parent component, but once i go to children one it starts breaking down

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, every time when i go to stack-overflow my brain gives me an answer after i post something.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
```

apparently its not good to have a dot in the beginning of href tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line on vue.config.js

```js
publicPath: ''
```